# how to get data from Input Form Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I am very new to this Cakephp framework, trying to follow and understand how to upload files using cakephp. I am using upload plugin provided by josediazgonzalez. In the view file, using formhelper i have:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('username');
        echo $this->Form->control('password');
        echo $this->Form->control('role');
        echo $this->Form->input('photo', ['type' => 'file']); 
        echo $this->Form->control('dir');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I want to print again the value that i submitted in my controller, what should i write? Something like:

```
$this->request->data;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$this->request->data is an array of data passed to your scirpt. You can use it to get field that you are interested in with, eg:

```
$data = $this->request->data;
$someVariable = $data["name"];
```

Or, you can access any field directly, by using data() accessor:

```
$someVariable = $this->request->data("name");
```

From this point, you can do anything you want with this variable.

One more thing - as $this->request->data and $this->request->data() are currently in deprecated state and will be removed in next version, I suggest to use $this->request->getData() instead. Usage is similar:

```
$this->request->getData(); //will return array of data passed
$this->request->getData("field_name"); //access to specific field
```

Comment: 1 more question, do you know about multiple files upload?, im having trouble with it too, select multiple but only 1 is upload and stored

Comment: You are using plugin that I do not know about, but you current file input should not allow to upload more than one file. But if you change your file input as follows: `$this->Form->input("photos.", ["type" => "file", "multiple"])` it will allow you to select multiple files. After submitting form, in request data there will be an array named "photos" - you can iterate through it and save all files.

Comment: my problem is that when i adding a dot after photos, i got the error "Cannot get an empty property". Do you have skype or something that i can contact for further info? :(

Comment: It's probably some sort of typo in your controller action, please update your question with your controller code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vicnoob/33d4ff1065071c998e24ac39dffb02e0

Here is the code @Szymon